# Sum of all file sizes in a folder down not adds up to what what ls or du show

Tags: linux, files, ls, disk-usage, size

I have downloaded couple of thousands file form a cloud. the download is done without any error. When I check the files occupied space in my hard drive is showing size, then what is shown on the cloud by almost 3 times less. However for each individual file, downloaded files have the same size with the one on the clouds. I ran the following command to sum of he size of the individual files I get the summation number which is very similar to what I see on the cloud:

*ls * -l | tr -s ' ' |awk ' {s+=$5} END {print s}'*

**15621628725**

simple *ls* command in he same folder gives me the number below:

**6147984k, 5.9G**

even the *du -h* command also shows the 5.9G

Any help to figure out the cause of this issue is highly appreciated.

Comment: Read especially the "Microscopic complications" section. It fully explains what is happening here. The "Why is the total from du different from the sum of the file sizes?" directly addresses why the two commands you use yield different sizes.